# Convert Ordinal String to its number

Tags: javascript

I want to Convert Ordinal String to its number
e.g

- "1st" to 1
- "2nd" to 2
- "3rd" to 3

...

Tried this function but return its ordinal, not the number

`function nth(n){return["st","nd","rd"][((n+90)%100-10)%10-1]||"th"}`

it should be the inverse of this function

Comment: Easiest way would be to print everything but the trailing st/nd/rd characters so you only keep the number

Answer (score 6):

just use `parseInt`

```js
console.log(parseInt("1st"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the last two characters because suffix has constant length.

```js
function toNum(str) {
  return parseInt(str.substring(0, str.length - 2));
}

console.log(toNum("1st"));
```

Comment: `parseInt()` does this automatically

Answer (score 0):

Simply Extract Numerical Values From The String using `parseInt()`

```
parseInt("1st");
```

This will extract 1 i.e. Integer from the String

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function `match(...)` with a [Regular Expression](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html) `/[0-9]+/`.

```
console.log("3rd".match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) // -> 3
console.log("52381st".match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) // -> 52381
```

Just doing `"3rd".match(/[0-9]+/)` returns an object with a bit of useful data, but just accessing the property `[0]` will give you the output you're looking for (if you don't want to do `parseInt` like the other answers are mentioning haha).